# Disruptor how to use his ring buffer to read a file?

Tags: java, performance, disruptor-pattern

I am looking to use dirsuptor ring buffer to parse a file. But i do not see how to set a range of value to the ring buffer.

In example below it seem. It loop to each item to assign it to the buffer. But me, i would like to assign directly x items.

When i do FileInputStream.read( byte[] bytes ), I would like put these bytes into the ring buffer.

Usually my buffer is twice bigger than bytes I read. Like this I could read another page while i am computing one ( eg bytes array length == buffer / 2 ):

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
// Preallocate RingBuffer with 1024 ValueEvents
Disruptor<ValueEvent> disruptor = new Disruptor<ValueEvent>(ValueEvent.EVENT_FACTORY, 1024, exec);

// Build dependency graph
RingBuffer<ValueEvent> ringBuffer = disruptor.start();

for (long i = 10; i < 2000; i++) {
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    // Two phase commit. Grab one of the 1024 slots
    long seq = ringBuffer.next();
    ValueEvent valueEvent = ringBuffer.get(seq);
    valueEvent.setValue(uuid);
    ringBuffer.publish(seq);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I find it very odd use of `Disruptor`. Why did you decide to do it?

Comment: If you still decide to use it: you will need to build a set of values first and then set it in one go. But WHY?

Comment: I would like to use it because i read a stream of bytes. his length is 'PAGE_SIZE * x' . the buffer can truncate provided data so i need to read forward. Using a ringbuffer will be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version [3.0.0](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor#300-released-10-apr-2013) of the Disruptor it has supported batch publication.

There are a variety of `publishEvents` methods on the `Ringbuffer` depending on how you wish to transform your events.

Given your sample code I suspect you want to look at [this](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/RingBuffer.java#L680-L689) version, and supply an array of `UUID`s. There are multiple versions depending on how many arguments you wish to pass to the translator.

The [alternative version](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/RingBuffer.java#L584-L597) is to capture the UUID in the `EventTranslator` it self.